# Prime Number Theorem w/o Complex Analysis

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I know about

"Simple analytic proof of the prime number theorem" Newman, 1980

However, is there a proof of the Prime Number Theorem without the use of complex analysis? (Real analysis is fine).

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://www.jstor.org/pss/1969455  Erdos and Selberg have an elementary proof.

Comment: Yes.  Do a net search.  Erdos and Selberg (if memory serves) each did a mostly non-analytic version.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.04

Comment: Indeed, Erdos and Selberg are cited in the second sentence of Newman's paper... http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321853

Comment: It is worthwhile to note that the Erdős-Selberg proof is nicely explained in Hardy-Wright: An introduction to the theory of numbers. See sections 22.14-22.16 there, especially Theorems 430 and 434.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf explains the classic proof in context (there is what amounts to a priority dispute).

Comment: For Selberg's side of the story, see the interview with him in BAMS 2008#4. http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-08-01223-8

Answer (score 8):

Another exposition of an elementary proof (that is, a proof not using complex analysis) is in Gerald Tenenbaum and Michel Mendes France, The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution, which is Volume 6 of the Student Mathematical Library, published by the American Mathematical Society. The proof they give is due to Daboussi, from 1984.

Comment: Somehow, I thought there is essentially just one "elementary" proof known, that due to Erdős and Selberg; do you mean, the proof you mention is substantially different?

Comment: @Seva: From the MR review of Daboussi's paper (written by Diamond):
"This paper gives an elementary proof of the PNT that is remarkable in that it makes no use of Selberg's now famous formula." 
Here is a link to the original paper of Daboussi http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~allouche/20060929144515189.pdf
(And then there are the other devlopments improving on the error term, Diamon-Steinig and so on.)

Answer (score 7):

There is a terrific exposition of the elementary proof by Terry Tao, available as the file prime.dvi [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/).  A more traditional exposition is available in Edwards's book *Riemann's zeta function*.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want $\pi(n) = \Omega \left( \frac{n}{\log n} \right)$, good enough for many applications, here is a quick proof: The highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $2n \choose n$ is at most $2n$ -- you get at most one more factor of $p$ in the numerator than denominator  for each power $p^i \leq 2n$. This tells you that ${2n \choose n} \leq (2n)^{\pi(2n)}$. So $\pi(2n) \geq \frac{\log_2 {2n \choose n}}{\log_2 (2n)} \geq \frac{n}{\log_2 (2n)}$.

Answer (score 5):

A nice exposition of an Erdos/Selberg-type elementary proof is given by Levinson in  Amer. Math. Monthly  76 (1969) 225–245.

The proof by Daboussi as written up by Tenenbaum and Mendes-France was already mentioned.

Yet another one is due to Hildebrand in  Mathematika  33 (1986) 23–30.